# Navbar doesn't fit to top

Tags: html, css

I'm  stuck with positioning.

```
body{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: 'Consolas';
letter-spacing: 2px
}

.navbar {
background-color: #595959;
color: #ffffff;
list-style: none;
text-align: center;
padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
}
```

[image: SS]

As you can see, even I set `margin/padding` to 0.  it doesn't fit to top. ( I mean this grey line above the navbar.)

Comment: please bring your HTML too

Comment: Please post a fiddle with the issue replicated and it will be easier for others to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing that your navbar is done with `ul`/`li` you need to reset the `padding` from `ul` (because it has `padding` by default)

so set `padding:0` to `ul`